# Nested Listed Needed to Converted as JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to find a best-case algorithm to make the nested list into a JSON.

```
Nested List
[["No","Ratios","2018","2019","2020"],["Profitability Ratio","Profitability Ratio","Profitability Ratio","Profitability Ratio","Profitability Ratio"],["1","Return on Assets (%)","-0.50","0.86","26.62"],["2","Return on Equity (%)","-0.51","0.87","27.14"],["3","Gross Profit Margin (%)","0.00","0.00","0.00"],["Liquidity Ratio","Liquidity Ratio","Liquidity Ratio","Liquidity Ratio","Liquidity Ratio"],["4","Current Ratio (times)","-0.50","0.86","26.62"],["5","Accounts Receivable Turnover (times)","-0.51","0.87","27.14"],["Operation Efficiency Ratio","Operation Efficiency Ratio","Operation Efficiency Ratio","Operation Efficiency Ratio","Operation Efficiency Ratio"],["6","Total Assets Turnover (times)","-0.50","0.86","26.62"],["7","Operation Expense to Total Revenue Ratio (%)","-0.51","0.87","27.14"]]

Beautified Nested List
[
   [
      "No",
      "Ratios",
      "2018",
      "2019",
      "2020"
   ],
   [
      "Profitability Ratio",
      "Profitability Ratio",
      "Profitability Ratio",
      "Profitability Ratio",
      "Profitability Ratio"
   ],
   [
      "1",
      "Return on Assets (%)",
      "-0.50",
      "0.86",
      "26.62"
   ],
   [
      "2",
      "Return on Equity (%)",
      "-0.51",
      "0.87",
      "27.14"
   ],
   [
      "3",
      "Gross Profit Margin (%)",
      "0.00",
      "0.00",
      "0.00"
   ],
   [
      "Liquidity Ratio",
      "Liquidity Ratio",
      "Liquidity Ratio",
      "Liquidity Ratio",
      "Liquidity Ratio"
   ],
   [
      "4",
      "Current Ratio (times)",
      "-0.50",
      "0.86",
      "26.62"
   ],
   [
      "5",
      "Accounts Receivable Turnover (times)",
      "-0.51",
      "0.87",
      "27.14"
   ],
   [
      "Operation Efficiency Ratio",
      "Operation Efficiency Ratio",
      "Operation Efficiency Ratio",
      "Operation Efficiency Ratio",
      "Operation Efficiency Ratio"
   ],
   [
      "6",
      "Total Assets Turnover (times)",
      "-0.50",
      "0.86",
      "26.62"
   ],
   [
      "7",
      "Operation Expense to Total Revenue Ratio (%)",
      "-0.51",
      "0.87",
      "27.14"
   ]
]
```

The above is the Nested list that need to be converted into a `JSON`. And below is the written JSON structure which is derived from the nested list.

```
{
"Head Key":[
      {
         "Profitability Ratio":[
            {
               "No":1,
               "Ratios":"Return on Assets (%)",
               "2018":"-0.50",
               "2019":"0.86",
               "2020":"26.62"
            },
            {
               "No":2,
               "Ratios":"Return on Equity (%)",
               "2018":"-0.51",
               "2019":"0.87",
               "2020":"27.14"
            },
            {
               "No":3,
               "Ratios":"Gross Profit Margin (%)",
               "2018":"0.00",
               "2019":"0.00",
               "2020":"0.00"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Liquidity Ratio":[
            {
               "No":4,
               "Ratios":"Current Ratio (times)",
               "2018":"-0.50",
               "2019":"0.86",
               "2020":"26.62"
            },
            {
               "No":5,
               "Ratios":"Accounts Receivable Turnover (times)",
               "2018":"-0.51",
               "2019":"0.87",
               "2020":"27.14"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Operation Efficiency Ratio":[
            {
               "No":6,
               "Ratios":"Total Assets Turnover (times)",
               "2018":"-0.50",
               "2019":"0.86",
               "2020":"26.62"
            },
            {
               "No":7,
               "Ratios":"Return on Assets (%)",
               "2018":"-0.51",
               "2019":"0.87",
               "2020":"27.14"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I am finding the best time complexity algorithm for the above problem using python language. Im bit confused what inbuilt function need to be used to solve this problem

Comment: A carefully crafted dictionary comprehension is what you need

Comment: @JCaesar yes i would say dynamic

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#json.dumps ...  Your "data" is ill suited - you need to mangle it into shape, then feed into json.dumps.  Get coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = [["No","Ratios","2018","2019","2020"],["Profitability Ratio","Profitability Ratio","Profitability Ratio","Profitability Ratio","Profitability Ratio"],["1","Return on Assets (%)","-0.50","0.86","26.62"],["2","Return on Equity (%)","-0.51","0.87","27.14"],["3","Gross Profit Margin (%)","0.00","0.00","0.00"],["Liquidity Ratio","Liquidity Ratio","Liquidity Ratio","Liquidity Ratio","Liquidity Ratio"],["4","Current Ratio (times)","-0.50","0.86","26.62"],["5","Accounts Receivable Turnover (times)","-0.51","0.87","27.14"],["Operation Efficiency Ratio","Operation Efficiency Ratio","Operation Efficiency Ratio","Operation Efficiency Ratio","Operation Efficiency Ratio"],["6","Total Assets Turnover (times)","-0.50","0.86","26.62"],["7","Operation Expense to Total Revenue Ratio (%)","-0.51","0.87","27.14"]]
result = dict()
for i in range(1, len(lst)):
    if not lst[i][0].isnumeric():
        key = lst[i][0]
        result[key] = []
    else:
        result[key].append({k: v for (k,v) in zip(lst[0], lst[i])})
print(result)
```